# How to use Observable to show data in template?

Tags: angular

Component has obsewrvable property:

```
public filteredEvents$: Observable<IEvent[]>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.events$ = this.eventsService.get(); // Load data from server
   this.filteredEvents$ = this.createFilter(this.filter$, this.events$).pipe(...); // Apply filter stream
}
```

Template is:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(filteredEvents$ | async).length; else nodata">
```

I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of null
> at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Seems it happens because initial value of observer is `undefined`, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either initialize `filteredEvents$` like this:

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';


public filteredEvents$: Observable<IEvent[]> = of([]);
```

Or use `?` operator in corresponding HTML code

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(filteredEvents$ | async)?.length; else nodata">
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try, could you explain me, why when I call method `checkAll()`, it sends request to server again: `this.eventsService.get();`

 `public checkAll(): void {
    this.filteredEvents$ = this.events$.pipe(
      map((events: IEvent[]) =>
        events.filter(
          (event: IEvent) => (event.checked_export = !event.checked_export)
        )
      )
    );
  }`

Comment: This `public filteredEvents$: Observable<IEvent[]> = of([]);` not helped me

Comment: About the comment, "it sends request to server again", it would help if you can create a separate question with stackblitz demo

Answer (score 0):

we probably don't need to call the `length` method, `filteredEvents$ | async` may suffice

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(filteredEvents$ | async); else nodata">
```